# Paper Input elements doesn't work in Polymer 2

Tags: web, polymer, components, polymer-2.x

I'm working with polymer 2, I download polymer paper input elements, then i add the link tag:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
```

then:

```
<paper-input  label="Floating label"></paper-input>
```

And the browser not showing the input text element

I'm working with the last version of chrome 56.0

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 9):

Look at [Polymer 2.0 installation Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20).

Have you installed paper-input with bower correctly?

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-input#2.0-preview
```

Comment: I installed everything correctly and still get this error in the log: `paper-input-container.html:513 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at HTMLElement.attached (paper-input-container.html:513)
    at HTMLElement.attached (class.html:207)...`

Comment: It was working before. Had to reinstall my bower components and it stoped working.